# Selecting Multiple Values from Same Coulmn

Tags: self-join

I want a query to find out who doesn't have a specific role (user, create or admin)

DB is Structured as Follows:

```
name_last | name_first | role
```

Sample Data:

```
brown | john | user |
brown | john | create |
brown | john | admin |
house | chris | user |
brady | bill | user |
pink | deb | user |
pink | deb | admin |
green | ashley | user |
green | ashley | create
```

Who doesn't have the create role?

```
select name_last, name_first, role
where role != ??
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you shouldn't repeat the name in each row. Create a table `user_account` and use a foreign key from that table to the `user_account` table.

Comment: Thank you Verace. I do use a separate table for the user_account with a foreign key. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a not exists query:

```
select distinct t1.name_last, t1.name_first
from the_table t1
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t1.name_last = t2.name_last
                    and t1.name_first = t2.name_first
                    and t2.role = 'create');
```

The NOT EXISTS operator returns "true" if the sub-select returns nothing. In this case the sub-select looks for any row with the same name as the outer row but with the role `create`